# python group by and count based on time in another column

Tags: python, datetime, group-by, count, apply

I'm trying to do group by and count the number of records that fit certain conditions using python.

The sample data is shown below. I want to create a new column 'phone_cnt' to show the number of calls that fits the following conditions: first, find the number that has at least one dept=0 record; then count the number of calls from the number which happen **AFTER** the dept=0 call

```
    np.random.seed(0)
    # create an array of 17 dates starting at '2015-02-24', one per hour
    rng = pd.date_range('2021-04-01', periods=17, freq='H')
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'time': rng, 'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17],
                      'phone':[881,453,453,111,347,767,767,980,767,453,453,767,767,687,321,243,243],
                     'dept': [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]}) 
    df
```

Expected results:
[phone 243 has phone_cnt=1; 453 has 3 counts, 767 has 3 counts, and 980 has 0 count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57iD3.png)

I've tried the steps below. The first 2 steps work, but step 3 is wrong.

```
    # step 1: create a list of unique phone numbers which have dept=0 in records
    phonelist = df[df['dept']==0].phone.unique()
         
    # step 2: find all the calls from the above calls
    df1 = df[df['phone'].isin(phonelist)].sort_values(by = ['phone','time'], ascending = [True, True])
    df1
        
    # step 3: count the number of calls in df1 that happened after the dept=0 call for each number
    df2 =df1.groupby('phone')['time'].apply(lambda x: x>df[df['dept']==0].time).sum()).reset_index(name='count')
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way from where you left off at `df1` using [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```py
from itertools import dropwhile

is_nonzero = lambda x: x != 0
df1.groupby("phone").dept.apply(lambda gr: len(list(dropwhile(is_nonzero, gr))) - 1)
```

gives

```
phone
243    1
453    3
767    3
980    0
Name: dept, dtype: int64
```

`dropwhile` drops the values while its predicate (i.e. nonzero-ness in this case) holds. This way we get a cropped group where only the first `0` and the remaining elements exist. Now we need the "length minus 1" of these guys. However, since `dropwhile` returns a "lazy" object, we invoke `list` first and then `len` on it. (`-1` at the end is because the desired values are *after* the first 0.)